# GPU not detected by Tensorflow V1

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I'm currently using Tf 1.1.0. I tried to list out the available devices by using the following command

```bash
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

It displayed only CPU but not GPU. When I ran the same command with tf 2.x.x, both CPU and GPU were displayed. Is there a way to make tf v1 detect my GPU,Coz I'm not willing to switch to tf v2

My model is being trained on CPU as tf isn't detecting the GPU

Comment: what GPU are you using? What's the driver and CUDA versions?

Comment: also are you using tensorflow 1.1 or tensorflow_gpu 1.1?

Comment: Hi, I'm using NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, Driver Version: 515.86.01 and CUDA Version: 11.7

Comment: I tried with both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu.  Nothing seems to work. And Thanks for the reply

Comment: Can you uninstall tensorflow, and install only tensorflow gpu?
Whats the result?

Answer (score -1):

If you are not willing to switch to TensorFlow 2.x, you can try updating your GPU drivers, and specifying which GPU to use when running TensorFlow. You can do this using the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable. For example:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python your_script.py
```

This will tell TensorFlow to use the first GPU (with an index of 0) when running your script. You can change the index to specify a different GPU.